# Dynamic dropdown set to autofill next column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The company I work for has a large amount of data stored in a Google Sheets and many different people have access to it and have edit access. To help keep things consistent I am setting up some formulas/scripts throughout the sheet.

What I am currently getting stuck on is basically a script that will run an IF formula and display a set value if the cell before it equals a specific value. So column K has a Data Validation dropdown made off of range in A1:I1, if I select a value it needs to just display whatever data is in the cell directly below that range. I know that this could be done with a simple VLOOKUP, but I'd rather not go about it that way if I don't have to. The current script I have is this:

```
function onEdit(){
  var tabPhase = "Authenticated";

  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var dataYear = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(tabPhase);

  var activeCell = spreadSheet.getActiveCell();

  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 11 && activeCell.getRow() > 1 && spreadSheet.getSheetName() == tabPhase){
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();
    var makes = dataYear.getRange(1, 1, 1, dataYear.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var makeIndex = makes[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 1;

    if(makeIndex != 0){
        var validationRange = dataYear.getRange(3, makeIndex, dataYear.getLastRow());
        var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
        activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRule);

     }   
  }   
  }
```

It works almost perfectly, the only issue that I'm running into is that the cell in column L then outputs a data validation.

I was also able to sort of get this to work using a nested if statement, however I'm not sure how to pull from a cell rather than just have it display previously set data. Here is that code:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var aSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var aCell = aSheet.getActiveCell();
  var aColumn = aCell.getColumn();
  var aRow = aCell.getRow();

  var licenseTypeCell = aSheet.getRange(aRow, aColumn+1);
  var aValue = aCell.getValue()
  if (aColumn == 1 && aSheet.getName() == 'Authenticated Ranges') {
      var matchCell = aSheet.getRange(aRow, aColumn).getValue()
if(matchCell == "A1")
  licenseTypeCell.setValue("A2");
    if(matchCell == "B1")
  licenseTypeCell.setValue("B2");
    if(matchCell == "C1")
  licenseTypeCell.setValue("C2");
    if(matchCell == "D1")
  licenseTypeCell.setValue("D2");
      }
  }
```

What can I change to make it show just the value in the second row rather than the data validation range that it is currently showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring this out after way too many hours spent working on it. Any suggestions to streamline this a bit are of course welcome, as I know this code is only functional and not very pretty!

```
function onEdit() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var aSheet = app.getActiveSheet();
  var aCell = aSheet.getActiveCell();
  var aColumn = aCell.getColumn();
  var aRow = aCell.getRow();
  var targetSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Authenticated");

  var A1 = targetSheet.getRange(2,1).getValue();
  var B1 = targetSheet.getRange(2,2).getValue();
  var C1 = targetSheet.getRange(2,3).getValue();
  var D1 = targetSheet.getRange(2,4).getValue();
  var E1 = targetSheet.getRange(2,5).getValue();

  var licenseTypeCell = aSheet.getRange(aRow, aColumn+1);

  var aValue = aCell.getValue()

  if (aColumn == 16 && aSheet.getName() == 'Master') {
      var matchCell = aSheet.getRange(aRow, aColumn).getValue()
    if(matchCell == "A1")
      licenseTypeCell.setValue(A1);
    if(matchCell == "B1")
      licenseTypeCell.setValue(B1);
    if(matchCell == "C1")
      licenseTypeCell.setValue(C1);
    if(matchCell == "D1")
      licenseTypeCell.setValue(D1);
    if(matchCell == "E1")
      licenseTypeCell.setValue(E1);
      }
  }
```